How to get return code of program executed on remote server from powershell?
Very important, this is powershell specific.
There are many answers to variations of this question whose answer is to use single quotes instead of double quotes
e.g. ssh me@server "invalid_program; echo $?" -> ssh me@server 'invalid_program; echo $?'
This is not possible on windows in powershell with openssh. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75740191/8652920
Given there is a restriction that I have to ssh with double quotes only, is there any way to still force the environment variable expansion to happen on remote?
You can try this on your powershell.
PS C:\...> ssh me@remote "beep; echo $?"
Warning: Permanently added 'remote' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
bash: beep: command not found
True

The stdout should be 127, not True.
% ssh me@remote 'beep; echo $?'
Warning: Permanently added 'remote' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
127
bash: beep: command not found


As an aside: $? is a shell(-only) variable, not an environment variable, both in POSIX-compatible shells and in PowerShell. Shell variables are only visible to the shell process at hand and copies are not inherited by child processes (with the limited exception of subshells in POSIX-compatible shells). In POSIX-compatible shells, shell variables and environment variables are referenced using the same syntax (e.g. $FOO; env. vars. are marked as such, typically with export), whereas PowerShell has a
distinct namespace for environment variables (e.g., $env:FOO).

Preface:

This [using single quotes] is not possible on windows in powershell with openssh.


In PowerShell (as opposed to in cmd.exe / batch files / no-shell invocations) using '...' when invoking external programs such as ssh does work even on Windows, because PowerShell translates such arguments into "..."-enclosed (double-quoted) arguments behind the scenes, assuming they contain spaces.[1]

Indeed, using '...' (a single-quoted string) is the simplest solution in your case - see the next section.



$ is a metacharacter in both PowerShell and POSIX-compatible shells such as bash, and in both shells "..." is an expandable i.e. interpolating string.
Therefore, in ssh me@remote "beep; echo $?", it is PowerShell that expands $?, up front,[2] using the then-current value of its definition of $?, which is a Boolean value.
To prevent unwanted up-front interpolation:

Either: Use ssh me@remote "beep; echo `$?", i.e. escape the embedded $ using PowerShell's escape character, ` (the so-called backtick)

Or: Use a verbatim string ('...'), to which no interpolation is applied by design:
ssh me@remote 'beep; echo $?'



[1] That is, PowerShell passes arguments that do not contain spaces unquoted on the process command line constructed behind the scenes. Unfortunately, this can break invocation of batch files (*.cmd, *.bat), because cmd.exe, the batch-file interpreter - inappropriately - parses its command line as if it had been passed from inside a cmd.exe session. Thus, an invocation from PowerShell such as .\foo.cmd 'a&b' breaks and requires awkward workarounds. GitHub issue #15143 is a proposal to prevent such problems, but, regrettably, it died from neglect.
Note that in Unix-like environments this point is moot, because there are no process command lines - argument are invariably passed as an array of verbatim strings.
[2] It follows from the above that if you were to run this command from a POSIX-compatible shell (i.e. from a Unix environment), undesired up-front interpolation would occur too, except that a number would be interpolated, namely the most recently executed command's exit code, which is what $? reflects in those shells.

im not sure if this wasn't clear, but I just did C:\...> to obscure my directory structure and repo name, since the stuff I work on is theoretically protected under confidentiality agreements and such, but the directory path isn't really relevant to this question anyway

@notacorn, it's unclear to me how your comment relates to the points I made in this answer. Independently, please see the preface I've added to the answer, which addresses the misconception that it isn't possible to use '...'-enclosed arguments when calling external programs in PowerShell.

I think I just needed the clarification for what ... meant, which seems to be "anything", so that's now been made clear.

I see, @notacorn. Yes, just like you did in the question, I used ... as a placeholder for something whose specifics are incidental to what is being explained. I frequently use '...' / "..." as representations of single- / double-quoted strings, because they're easy to recognize visually. With this clarification out of the way, I think this answer addresses your question as asked and solves your problem.

wow this is amazing thanks!!

Glad to hear it helped, @notacorn; my pleasure. Thanks for the nice feedback.
